# Ubuntu 18.04 x64 time format with nodejs

Tags: format, time

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 x64 on VPS, I never used it before.

I created huge nodejs script with

- new Date().toLocaleTimeString() and  new Date().toLocaleDateString

commends, on Windows 10 everything works great, but on Ubuntu because of 12 hour format my nodejs script is in total mess.

I want to change ubuntu settings instead of changing nodejs script.

I'm from Poland and I'm using 24 hour format.
I already changed something :D with console command, my time in ubuntu terminal looks like this:

```
root@node:~# date
Thu Nov 29 16:18:24 CET 2018

root@node:~# sudo timedatectl
                      Local time: Thu 2018-11-29 16:31:15 CET
                  Universal time: Thu 2018-11-29 15:31:15 UTC
                        RTC time: Thu 2018-11-29 15:31:16
                       Time zone: Europe/Warsaw (CET, +0100)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

but in nodejs console I see:

```
[4:02:20 PM]
```

on Windows:

```
[2018-11-29][14:55:01]
```

on Ubuntu

```
[11/29/2018][4:00:33 PM]
```

Because of symbol '/' in date on Ubuntu my script can't create new .txt files with date

Please help me :D
Thank you & Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Set shell variable `LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8`. I tried with LC_TIME but it doesn't work.

PS: Don't mess with `date`, it doesn't do anything in this case (only SHOWS time)

Comment: -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (pl_PL.UTF-8): No such file or directory

Comment: oh sorry, I use german where it's de_DE. Apparently for Polish it's `LC_ALL=pl`

Comment: I really don't get it, what I'm doing wrong here, should I just paste here into terminal with PuTTY? -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (pl): No such file or directory

Comment: `LC_ALL=pl_PL-UTF-8 node` to run only nodejs one time with LC_ALL or `export LC_ALL=pl_PL-UTF-8` for the whole session (i.e. until you close the terminal window) or put `LC_ALL=pl_PL-UTF-8` `export LC_ALL` (two separate lines) in your `.bashrc` for setting the variable permanently, although this might change the language of the OS completely to Polish, I'm not sure.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/cCAiQxr.png - I have no idea what I'm doing with this system

Comment: oh, you don't have the locale file. Edit `/etc/locale.gen` and add `pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8` and then run `locale-gen` as root. Then try setting LC_ALL or LC_TIME again.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've checked your screenshot and you've got a tipo. It's `pl_PL.UTF-8` (with a dot) and not `pl_PL-UTF-8`. Try setting it again and only if it doesn't work, try generating the locale fine with locale-gen as described above

Comment: everything is fine now, thank you, already added export to .profile file, and my nodejs scripts works like in Windows env - thank you so much! I did before: localedef -i pl_PL -c -f UTF-8 pl_PL.UTF-8 because I have read it on some polish forum, I dont know what it changed

Comment: it does the same thing as locale-gen. I'm glad it's working